# Conan not respecting compiler.libcxx abi setting

Tags: c++, conan

I have the following conan profile:

```
$ conan profile show default
Configuration for profile default:

[settings]
os=Linux
os_build=Linux
arch=x86_64
arch_build=x86_64
compiler=gcc
compiler.version=11
compiler.cppstd=20
compiler.libcxx=libstdc++
build_type=Release
[options]
[conf]
[build_requires]
[env]
```

Note that `compiler.libcxx` is the old ABI (`libstdc++`) and not the new ABI (`libstdc++11`). This is intentional. Also I'm specifying `cppstd=20`.

I then made a custom conanfile for `{fmt}`, which tries to package up fmt 9.0. That looks like, in its entirety:

```py
from conans import ConanFile, CMake, tools
from conan.tools.cmake import CMakeToolchain, cmake_layout

class ConanFmt(ConanFile):
    name = "fmt"
    version = "9.0.0"

    settings = "os", "compiler", "cppstd", "build_type", "arch"

    def source(self):
        git = tools.Git(folder="fmt")
        git.clone("https://github.com/fmtlib/fmt.git", "9.0.0", shallow=True)

    def layout(self):
        cmake_layout(self)

    def generate(self):
        tc = CMakeToolchain(self)
        tc.generate()

    def build(self):
        cmake = CMake(self)
        cmake.definitions["FMT_DOC"] = False
        cmake.definitions["FMT_TEST"] = False
        cmake.definitions["FMT_INSTALL"] = True
        cmake.definitions["CMAKE_EXPORT_COMPILE_COMMANDS"] = True
        cmake.configure(source_folder="fmt")
        cmake.build()

    def package(self):
        cmake = CMake(self)
        cmake.install()

    def package_info(self):
        self.cpp_info.libs = ["fmt"]
```

When I try to go ahead and package this up, like say:

```
$ conan create . demo/testing -s build_type=Release
```

This does actually go ahead and clone the `{fmt}` repo, and correctly build and package up the contents of the library.

Except that:

- there is no `_GLIBCXX_USE_CXX11_ABI` definition set (despite what [this page](https://docs.conan.io/en/latest/howtos/manage_gcc_abi.html#manage-gcc-abi)) says.
- `{fmt}` was compiled with C++11, not C++20
- ... but it *was* built with `Release` (`-O3 -DNDEBUG`)

Conan does appear to provide variables like `CONAN_CMAKE_CXX_STANDARD=20`, `CONAN_STD_CXX_FLAG=-std=c++2a`, and `CONAN_LIBCXX=libstdc++`. But `{fmt}`'s build doesn't actually use those, so that isn't very useful.

How do I actually get conan to propagate through these fields properly? Is that something that must be explicitly specified in the `conanfile.py` (even if it's in the profile)?

Comment: It seems you are mixing the legacy ``CMake`` command wrapper with the new one. If you are using ``CMakeToolchain``, you need to use the matching ``from conan.tools.cmake import CMake`` helper too.

Comment: As a general hint, you want to avoid the ``from conans`` import, and use ``from conan.tools.scm import Git``, ``from conan import ConanFile``, to use the modern tools that will survive in Conan 2.0 (already in beta). See https://docs.conan.io/en/latest/reference/conanfile/tools.html

Comment: @drodri The `conan.tools.cmake.CMake` version apparently doesn't have `definitions`. Do you know how to set those? I see no documentation for this.

Comment: Yes, to add that info in the new tooling, you want to have a look at the CMakeToolchain https://docs.conan.io/en/latest/reference/conanfile/tools/cmake/cmaketoolchain.html, you can add ``.variables`` for your own CMake variables (will be stored in the ``conan_toolchain.cmake``, ``.preprocessor_definitions`` for #defines and ``.cache_variables`` that map to ``CMakePresets`` cache variables that map to command line. The idea is that everything is defined at ``generate()`` time, and ``build()`` time is dummy,

Comment: @drodri The new `CMake` also doesn't have a way to specify the source folder.

Comment: @Barry It's part of the layout. Please, read the official getting started guide, which uses the modern approach: https://docs.conan.io/en/latest/creating_packages/getting_started.html#getting-started